# missing 1 required positional argument:'self' when assigning a method to a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a method's return to a variable and stuck with this error.

```
class MyClass():

    def my_def(self):
        return "Hello"

    my_variable = my_def()
```

Here is the Java equivalent of what I want to do.

```
public class NewException {
    public int method1(){

        return 1;
    }
    public int variable = method1();
}
```

I am sure this is something simple, but I couldn't even find the right words to google this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's good to put the whole error in the body of your question.

Comment: This would set a class attribute on `MyClass`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want to do. Can you please explain the context of that code, so we can give advise on how to do it right.

Comment: Also take a look at PEP8, camelCase in method names hurt my eyes (yes, I'm a PEP8 nazy).

Comment: Your question needs more context.  The code block you offer doesn't make sense. If you really need to do this you could make myDef a classmethod instead of an instance method.  Also, as Paulo mentions, you should use the variable my_variable instead of myvariable and my_def instead of myDef.

Comment: You need to do that a) outside of the class and b) with an object instance. If that does not mean anything to you. Please do the Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/ Chapter 9 will cover classes and objects.

Comment: I have a django view with a POST method. And this method user the get_serializer_class() which returns a serializer. Now for GET requests I do not have a GET method and do not intend to have one. I want to set the method to the serializer_class variable which can be used by all other types of requests.

Comment: I understand that I can put it in the get_serializer_class method but wanted to see how to do this in python. Something similar to this in Java                                                             --------public class NewException {
 public int method1(){  
  return 1;
 }
 public int variable = method1(); 
}

Comment: You should have put your main problem in the question. Instead you imagined how it would work in Java and assumed that it is the same in Python.

Comment: Yes, I should have. But got the answer finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with the difference between methods and functions, basically a method belongs to some object while a function does not. So for example

```
def myFunction():
    return "F"

class MyClass:
    value = 0
    def myMethod(self, value):
        old = self.value
        self.value = value
        return old

myClassInstance = MyClass()
print myClassInstance.myMethod(3)
# 0
print myClassInstance.myMethod(33)
# 3
print myFunction()
# F
```

Notice that the method is bound to the instance and it doesn't make sense to call the method before the instance is created. With that in mind, your error should make more sense. The method cannot be called without an instance (self). This is not the only kind of method, for example there are "static methods". Static methods are defined on the class, but they are called without an instance. For example:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def myStaticMethod():
        return "static method"
    # Consider using an instance attribute instead of a class attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute = MyClass.myStaticMethod()
# Or if you need a class attribute it needs to go outside the class block
MyClass.class_attribute = MyClass.myStaticMethod()
```

Comment: That means I cannot assign the static methods return value to a class variable directly, Right?

Comment: It's not that you can't "assign directly", it's that the class object doesn't exist until the end of the class block. Unlike functions, you cannot have recursive calls to class objects in the class block so `MyClass.myStaticMethod` needs to be called outside the class block. There is no downside to doing it this way except it's a little uglier.