# Reportlab Error after page break

Tags: python, reportlab

I am designing a two page form to be printed duplex.  After I add a pagebreak, I get the following error:

```
    File "f:\Dropbox\pms\pms_reports.py", line 450, in <module>
  a = Key_card1()
File "f:\Dropbox\pms\pms_reports.py", line 441, in __init__
  doc.build(elements)
File "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 1171, in build
  BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
File "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 927, in build
  self.handle_flowable(flowables)
File "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 775, in handle_flowable
  self.handle_keepWithNext(flowables)
File "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 742, in handle_keepWithNext
  while i<n and flowables[i].getKeepWithNext(): i += 1

builtins.TypeError: getKeepWithNext() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is my code:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

    class Key_card1():
    def __init__(self, start_date=datetime.now(), room="1", 
           end_date=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1), password = "999999"):
        stylesheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate("key_card.pdf", pagesize=A4)

        if password == "999999":
            password = str(random.randint(10000,99999))

        roomno = "Room" + room
        w_text = []
        w_text.append(Paragraph("To use the wireless broadband…:",stylesheet["BodyText"]))
        w_text.append(Paragraph("User id: <b>" + roomno + "</b>", stylesheet["BodyText"]))
        w_text.append(Paragraph("Password: <b>" + password + "</b>", stylesheet["BodyText"]))

        message_text = []
        message_text.append(Paragraph("Our current menus ...", stylesheet["BodyText"]))
        message_text.append(Paragraph("Our restaurant can get very busy ...",stylesheet["BodyText"])) 
        message_text.append(Paragraph("Your shower has a safety device to...", stylesheet["BodyText"]))
        message_text .append(Paragraph("Please do not hesitate to call...",stylesheet["BodyText"]))


        elements=[]
        table_data = [(w_text, message_text)]
        the_table = Table(table_data)
        the_table.setStyle(TableStyle([('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE')]))
        elements.append(the_table)
        elements.append(PageBreak)

        #Cover page
        logo= "y:\marketing\priory_master_logo bw.jpg"
        im = Image(logo, 3*cm, 1.258*cm)

        cover_data = []
        cover_data.append(im)
        cover_data.append(Paragraph("Room number : " + room, stylesheet["BodyText"]))
        left_cell =[]
        left_cell.append(Paragraph(" ", stylesheet["BodyText"]))


        table_data1 = [(left_cell, cover_data)]
        the_table1 = Table(table_data1)
        the_table1.setStyle(TableStyle([('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE')]))
        elements.append(the_table1)


        doc.build(elements)
```

I tried modifying the Reportlab modules but I was not successful.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to understand the error and i guess there is problem in
`doc = SimpleDocTemplate("key_card.pdf", pagesize=A4)`.The problem may be the argument "key_card.pdf". I'm not sure

Edit: Maybe, `BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)` problem is about "flowables" argument which is connected to elements in doc.build(elements)

SOLUTION -> elements.append(PageBreak) should be elements.append(PageBreak())

Comment: I converted the code creating a pageTemplate and Frame and used BaseDocTemplate and got exactly the same error.  When I comment out the pagebreak, it all prints without error (except no pagebreak).

Comment: i guess i found it `elements.append(PageBreak)` should be  `elements.append(PageBreak())`. i googled "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" and found these [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289391/missing-1-required-positional-argumentself-when-assigning-a-method-to-a-varia) u should be careful about class initialization ;)

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I don't know why I did not see it.  If you make your comment an answer, I will acept it. - Thanks!